# Newtonsoft. JSON reports an error. How can I solve it?

Tags: c#, json

The code is written like this：

```
public class Value
        {
            public string Remote_server { get; set; }
            public string Game_version { get; set; }
        }
        public class RootObject
        {
            public Value[] @Config { get; set; } // Json字段名
        }

        public void Window_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
            string conf = path + @"mchmr\config.json";

            var objJSON = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(conf);
            string url = objJSON.Config[0].Remote_server;
            Data_1.Text = url;
```

This is the content of the JSON file:

```
{
    "Config": [
        {
            "Remote_server": "https://www.test.com/mchr/server_config.json",
            "Game_version": "0.9"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the error content of vs:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException:“Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: D. Path '', line 0, position 0.”
```

The error code is:

```
var objJSON = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(conf);
```

My English is not good, please forgive me.

Comment: `conf = path + @"mchmr\config.json";` you haven't read the file, `conf` just contains the file path.

Comment: I'll try it` JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(conf));
                while (reader.Read())`,But this is the result.

Comment: Try `string conf = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(path, "mchmr", "config.json"));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an alternate way to do it:

```
var path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
var conf = path + @"mchmr\config.json";
// You missed this line probably.
var jsonStr = string.Join(string.Empty, File.ReadAllLines(conf));
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

this is what I would be using

```
     string json = string.Empty;
     using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader( @jsonfilepath)) json = r.ReadToEnd();

     var objJSON = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```